# Font-Size issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I set the font-size of a table-data with JQuery to 70px but when I inspect the element with firebug it has 83px height, so my question is, how can I know what will be the real height of the table-data when I set the font-size with an specific value.
Inspecting the element with firebug I realize that the extra height is because of the special characters like "Ñ" and "j"
PD: The table-data it hasn't have any padding, margin, or border.

Comment: Show as your project, will be easier

Comment: The only way I know of is to actually measure it. Typically I use a hidden div with the text in, set the properties, and get its height. This isn't something you'll want to do often though.

Comment: Thanks Dave is a good idea

Comment: I think you should also take into consideration the 'line-height' css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inspect the `line-height`. I setup an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/ubR55/1/) for you.

Comment: your fiddle prints "normal" for line-height on my computer. Also this won't work if the text wraps (as it does in your example)